# Date time format for 2018-12-21 10:57 GMT+0

Tags: datetime, webmethod

I am having trouble finding the correct currentPattern for "2018-12-21 10:57 GMT+0" when i use dateTimeFormat in Webmethods does anyone know what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm zZ

Taken from Integration server built in references 10.1 "Pattern String Symbols"

```
y = year
MM = month in year
dd = day in month
HH = hour in day (0-23)
mm = minute in hour
z = time zone
Z = RFC 822 time zone (although this is 4 digits)
```